# iis 10 windows 10 date format

Tags: date, iis, date-format, windows-10

I migrated with my dev environment from win 8.1 to win 10 recently.

I have integration test which starts IIS Express process, runs webapi website and then calls requests on it. One of requests has date as a parameter. Globalization settings are forced in application web.config.

On win 8.1 IIS was handling date format as it was described in web.config and test was green. After win 10 migration I noticed that test is red. I investigated this case and I noticed that IIS (full version of IIS and IIS Express) is handling dates in different format than before (MM-dd-yyyy instead of dd-MM-yyyy).

I changed all regional settings available in system (including language setting for all accounts) but it did not help.

I forced also specified culture on globalization IIS settings in machine.config and global web.config (Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config) but with no result.

Has anybody noticed similar problems?

Comment: I just experienced this too and have opened a question about this (not having seen yours): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317505/windows-10-short-date-format-in-asp-net-application-inconsistent

Answer (score 2):

1. Open IIS Manager > Application Pools and locate your Application Pool (like DefaultAppPool etc.)
2. Select your Application Pool and click Advanced Settings.
3. Click Process Model > Identity
4. Set a Custom Account. This user should be in your computer's Local Users.
5. Make sure this user has the correct DateTime format.

Hope this helps.