# Windows 10 short date format in ASP.NET application inconsistent

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I have a new Windows 10 install and I'm migrating an existing ASP.NET app onto the box from a Windows 7 box where it runs fine.

I've noticed that on the Windows 10 box, dates are rendered in the format M/d/yy even though I have specifically set the date under region to be M/d/yyyy (note that 4 digit year). The date is rendered correctly in a browser, but when I'm connecting to localhost IIS still renders dates internally with the front short date format, which presents a bunch of validation issues when parsing.

Anyone have any idea? After changing my region settings, I've restarted. I also tried changing the IIS process identity to Network Service rather than APPPOOL as somebody mentioned that might make a difference. It did not.

Why would IIS not respect my regional settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We discovered that the issue is the user used by the AppPool inherits from a default user, which on Windows 10 begins with a short date format of M/d/yy. This needs to be first be changed and set as the default for new users, and then you need to create a new AppPool identity that has a different name than any existing (or deleted) identity. Ugh. But this works.

Basic steps:

1. Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Change date, time, or number formats
2. Set desired short date format (for me it was M/d/yyyy)
3. Click Apply
4. Go to Administrative tab and then click Copy settings
5. Check both boxes and click OK
6. Restart for good measure, though I don't recall if this is required
7. In IIS create a new AppPool identity and assign it to your site

The ASP.NET app should now use the date format that is expected. It is worth repeating that the AppPool identity has to have a different name. Even removing an identity, restarting, and creating one with the same name doesn't fix this issue. But creating one with a new, unique name does.